# Symfony2 forms and many to many relation

Tags: symfony

(Symfony version 2.7)

Hi, I have a problem with form in field with many to many relation.

```
Class Notification {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->assigneduser = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->flags = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Flag", inversedBy="notificationflags", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="sla_notificationflags",
 *                  joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="notification_id", referencedColumnName="notificationId")},
 *                  inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="flag_id", referencedColumnName="flagId")}
 *               )
 *
*/
private $flags;

/**
 * Add flag
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Flag $flag
 * @return Notification
 */
public function addFlag(Flag $flag)
{
    $flag->addNotificationflag($this);
    $this->flags[] = $flag;
    return $this;
}

}

Class Flag {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->notificationflags = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Notification", mappedBy="flags")
 */
protected $notificationflags;

/**
 * Add notificationflags
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Notification $notificationflag
 * @return Flag
 */
public function addNotificationflag(Notification $notificationflag)
{

    if(!$this->notificationflags->contains($notificationflag)) {
        $this->notificationflags->add($notificationflag);
    }

    return $this;
}



}
```

My Form Class

```
class NotificationSingleFormType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('flags','entity',array(
            'label' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'select'
            ),
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Flag',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->addOrderBy('p.name','ASC');
            },
            'property' => 'name',
            'required' => false
    )
    );
}
```

}

When i send the form i see error:

> Neither the property "flags" nor one of the methods
>   "addFlag()"/"removeFlag()", "setFlags()", "flags()", "__set()" or
>   "__call()" exist and have public access in class
>   "AppBundle\Entity\Notification".

Comment: Symfony tries to find the mandory methods to get the flags, add or remove a flag but could not find them inside the entity so you should add them. You could do that using the cli: php app/console doctrine:generate:entities

Answer (score 0):

You have to genrate getters/setters and add/remove methods of flag attribute.

use `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities` to generate them automatically

Comment: I generale the metod . Not all code paste to thread. I have all metod. I run app/console doctrine:generale:entities. I dont know why form not use them.